# More pythonic way of iteratively assigning csv rows to dictionary values?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a CSV file, with columns holding specific values that I read into specific places in a dictionary, and rows separate instances of data that equal one full dictionary.  I read in and then use this data to computer certain values, process some of the inputs, etc., for each row before moving on to the next row.  My question is, if I have a header that specifics the names of the columns (Key1 versus Key 3A, etc.), can I use that information to avoid the somewhat draw out code I am currently using (below).

```
    with open(input_file, 'rU') as controlFile:
    reader = csv.reader(controlFile)
    next(reader, None)  # skip the headers
    for row in reader:
        # Grabbing all the necessary inputs
        inputDict = {}
        inputDict["key1"] = row[0]
        inputDict["key2"] = row[1]
        inputDict["key3"] = {}
        inputDict["key3"].update({"A" : row[2]})
        inputDict["key3"].update({"B" : row[3]})
        inputDict["key3"].update({"C" : row[4]})
        inputDict["key3"].update({"D" : row[5]})
        inputDict["key3"].update({"E" : row[6]})

            inputDict["Key4"] = {}
            inputDict["Key4"].update({"F" : row[7]})
            inputDict["Key4"].update({"G" : float(row[8])})
            inputDict["Key4"].update({"H" : row[9]})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a `DictReader`, you can improve your code a bit:

> Create an object which operates like a regular reader but maps the
>   information read into a dict whose keys are given by the optional
>   fieldnames parameter. The fieldnames parameter is a sequence whose
>   elements are associated with the fields of the input data in order.
>   These elements become the keys of the resulting dictionary. If the
>   fieldnames parameter is omitted, the values in the first row of the
>   csvfile will be used as the fieldnames.

So, if we utilize that:

```
import csv
import string

results = []
mappings = [
             [(string.ascii_uppercase[i-2], i) for i in range(2, 7)],
             [(string.ascii_uppercase[i-2], i) for i in range(7, 10)]]

with open(input_file, 'rU') as control_file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(control_file)
    for row in reader:
        row_data = {}
        row_data['key1'] = row['key1']
        row_data['key2'] = row['key2']
        row_data['key3'] = {k:row[v] for k,v in mappings[0]}
        row_data['key4'] = {k:row[v] for k,v in mappings[1]}
        results.append(row_data)
```

Comment: Even better, if you turn the whole thing into a generator that `yield`s a `dict`, you could just `results = [row for row in get_rows('filename')]`, which neatly avoids the `append()`.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can.

```
import csv
with open(infile, 'rU') as infile:
     reader = csv.DictReader(infile)
     for row in reader:
          print(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this piece of code.

```
    fields = csv_data.next()

    for row in csv_data:
        parsed_data.append(dict(zip(fields,row)))
```